# Zip a folder named dash

Tags: zip

Zip folder which contain a folder named - , it can't be zip

folder structure

```
~/-
~/b.txt
~/-/a.txt
```

command

```
cd ~
zip -r abc.zip .
```

will stuck

```
~# zip -r abc.zip .
  adding: -
```

I used strace (read(0)), it seems zip treat the folder as a -(standard input).

how can zip folder which contain a folder which name is dash(-)

Comment: Can you please complete your question? Are you allowed to simply rename the "-" folder? That could be the simplest solution to your problem.

Comment: no I can't change the name of the folder

Answer (score 0):

You can create zip on this way:

```
zip -r file.zip -/* b*
```

I know, its not so elegant but it work.
Or you can use `tar` on such way:

```
tar cvf file.tar .
```

Comment: thanks for your help. however i'm look for zip command who can just zip the entire folder without me knowing what is inside the folder